# Preseed deletes data on partitions, how can I stop this?

Tags: partitioning, preseed

Here is my main preseed file:

```
# Partition Disks
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              30000 30000 30000 btrfs                         \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ btrfs }   \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              8000 8000 8000 linux-swap                       \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ swap }    \
                      $primary{ }                             \
              .                                               \
              30000 30000 30000 ext4                          \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
              use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
              mountpoint{ /data }             \
              label{ data }               \
              .                           \
              15000 15000 15000 ext4                          \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /work }                      \
              label{ work }               \
              .

d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm boolean  true
d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

And this is the preseed that should format and do a fresh install, but not touch the partitions or the data on the partitions:

```
# Partition Disks  
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              30000 30000 30000 btrfs                         \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ btrfs }   \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              8000 8000 8000 linux-swap                       \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ swap }    \
                      $primary{ }                             \
              .                                               \
              30000 30000 30000 ext4                          \
                      method{ keep }                          \
                      label{ data }                           \
              .                                               \
              15000 15000 15000 ext4                          \
                      method{ keep }                          \
                      label{ work }                           \
              .

partman-basicfilesystems partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm boolean  true
d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

After running the install with this preseed, the files within data and work are gone.

I have looked at 
https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/PartMan and set the method to keep but sadly still no luck.

The partitions are fine and still remaind, just the files within the partitions are gone.

My end goal is to have a unattended installation where it will format and restaill ubuntu, but still keep the partitions and the data still intact.

Thank you!

Comment: I have found [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/reinstall-os-keeping-other-partitions-intact-with-preseed-4175616241/) but I don't understand it fully. I don't know, perhaps it is still helpful

Answer (score 0):

The partman documentation has some good tips:
https://sources.debian.org/src/debian-installer/20190410/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt/

First of all, I believe you could define one of the partitions with "infinite" size, which will actually use whatever space is left on the device after all the other partitions' sizes have been calculated, for example:

```
              30000 30000 -1 ext4       \
                  method{ format }      \
                  format{ }             \
                  use_filesystem{ }     \
                  filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /data }   \
                  label{ data }         \
```

Anyways, have you found a way of keeping the data in the partition?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, just formatting os but data remains and mounted.

All you have to do is, put method{ format } but remove format{ }.

format{ } is the tag that does the formatting, if its not there, then the data is not removed.
Finally..

```
method{ format }              \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }   \
mountpoint{ /data }           \
```